# Using cipher with a socket java, not working

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

I have the following problem 
I have two programs, a client android and a server java 
In a point of program, the client has to send a crypted information with an instantiate cipher AES of java, but I don't know how it must be send to server.
In the previous code I used ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream as streams on socket java and it's working, but now I don't know.
This is the piece of interested code.

[CLIENT]
[CODE]

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec ivparameters = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES"), ivparameters);

             //and here I have to sent a string(the string is the SHA512 of a password

    byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(passwordHash.getBytes());
    oos.writeObject(new String(encryptedText));
    oos.flush();
```

[\CODE]

[SERVER]
[CODE]

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    IvParameterSpec ivparameters = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES"), ivparameters);

              //and here I have to read a string sent from client

    String textToRead = (String) ois.readObject();
    String decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(textToRead.getBytes()));
```

[\CODE]

I use in both programs ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream
I also try to use the method writeObject of ObjectOutputStream, but I don't know how to encrypt the object using cipher java.  Help me!!!!

I modify the code but I have this error

javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)

Comment: Use a CipherOutputStream between the ObjectOutputStream and the socket, and similarly on input.

Comment: I also tried a CipherOutputStream and a CipherInputStream, but how can I write the object? Can you show me the code for this solution?

Comment: The code for new ObjectOutoutStream(new CipherOutputStream(...))? Is it really so mysterious?

Comment: No, but I have also a global ObjectOutputStream for the socket. If I create another ObjectOutputStream so I have two streams and it can make a problem. I tried to create a new CipherOutputStream with ObjectOutputStream as parameter

Comment: So put it under the global ObjectOutputStream. I didn't say anything about using two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt, save in a serializable object, get the outputstream from the socket, and create a ObjectOutputstream with the socket's outputstream.  Here is an example.
Hope it helps.

```
package test.cipher;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

public class CipherTest {


    public void runTest() throws Exception{
        KeyGenerator generator=KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        generator.init(256);
        SecretKey key=generator.generateKey();

        byte[] bytes=new byte[16];
        (new Random()).nextBytes(bytes);
        IvParameterSpec spec=new IvParameterSpec(bytes);

        Server s=new Server(key,spec);
        Client c=new Client(key,spec);

        s.startListening();
        c.sendMessage("Hi there");
        c.sendMessage("this is a test");
        c.sendMessage("The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plains.");

        MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.update("The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plains.  The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plains.  The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plains. The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plains. The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plains. ".getBytes());
        byte[] digest=md.digest();
        c.sendHash(digest);

        s.stopServer();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        CipherTest t=new CipherTest();
        t.runTest();
    }

}

class Message implements Serializable{
    byte[] message; 
    public static Message createMessageFromHash(byte[] hash){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b:hash){
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return new Message(sb.toString().getBytes());
    }

    public Message(byte[] bytes) {
        message=bytes;
   }
}

class Server implements Runnable{
    Cipher cipher;
    ServerSocket server;
    boolean wasStopped=false;
    Thread serverThread;

    public Server(SecretKey key,IvParameterSpec spec) {
        try {
            cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,spec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void startListening() throws IOException{
        server=new ServerSocket(9189);
        Thread t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        serverThread=Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            if (server!=null){
                while (!wasStopped){
                    Socket clientSocket=server.accept();                
                    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    Message message=(Message)ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println( new String(cipher.doFinal(message.message)) );
                    ois.close();
                }
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void stopServer(){
         serverThread.interrupt();
         wasStopped=true;
         try {
             serverThread.join(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         serverThread=null;
         server=null;
    }
}


class Client{
    Cipher cipher;

public Client(SecretKey key, IvParameterSpec spec){
        try {
            cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendHash(byte[] hash) throws Exception{
        Socket server=new Socket("localhost", 9189);
        Message message=Message.createMessageFromHash(hash);
        System.out.println(new String(message.message));
        byte[] ciphertext=cipher.doFinal(message.message);
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(new Message(ciphertext));
        oos.close();
 }
    public void sendMessage(String message) throws Exception{
        Socket server=new Socket("localhost", 9189);
        byte[] ciphertext=cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject(new Message(ciphertext));
        oos.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I also try with encode and decode of base64 of apache commons codec library, but I have padding error

Comment: Did you set IV to be length 16?

Comment: Yes IV are 16 byte, and cipherKey is 32 byte

Comment: Now the problem is :   javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)

Comment: Can you send a HexString? I can send a SHA-512 message digest if I take the digest and convert it to a hex string.  [see an example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/).  Of course then you have to get the bytes like any other string.

Comment: Yes, I try also with HexString but doesn't working. In the client I write                                                              char[] HexText = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex(encryptedText); oos.writeObject(new String(HexText));                                               and in the server                                                                                           byte[] decodedText = Hex.decodeHex(textToRead.toCharArray());
String decryptedText = new String(cipher.doFinal(decodedText));

Comment: try using cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKey key, Byte[] IV);  and the Decrypt instead of Cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(cipherKey, "AES"), ivparameters)  Make sure the key is a SecretKey

Comment: I modified my code to show you how I pass the hash.  It works for me.  You must be passing the a byte[] that is not properly padded.